# EXCEL: find matching values

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

the following problem: I have an array of tables of witch I want to get a sum range of matching values. Here is the sheet:
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ja6b.jpg)
The matching values do not have to be exact matches. For example, for 28car.com I am interested in 28car, car28 or 28 car, so values which closely resemble the website keyword. This is because these keywords are based on queries from search keywords of the respective websites and may be prone to change. 
SUMIFS would therefore not work as I can only find exact matches (and these keywords may change on a monthly basis). I thought about VLOOKUP or INDEX & MATCH, but I don't know how to possibly execute either two. 
Any suggestions?

https://imgur.com/a/OtzkE

Comment: Don't just screenshot, input the data table here

Answer (score 0):

well you can use VLOOKUP with true as the last parameter i think, that will give you a non-exact matching word.

Alternatively you could add another table whith all the options for the KEY you would like to find.

Maybe if you give a little more information or some sort of image, we can help you better.